# Has Instagram API changed standard_resolution?

Tags: instagram, media, instagram-api

I'm working on an app to get photos from Instagram API with a specified tag.

Last week, when I requested for an image, the standard_resolution URL returned a 640x640 image, but now doing exactly the same the image is 320x320

I know from 1st June there are some changes in Instagram API.
Can anyone tell me about the size that the API can return when using Tag EndPoint?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

With the new Instagram 1st June change, the images won't necessarily be square anymore.

> As announced in the blog post, in addition to square posts, people can now share photos and videos in both portrait and landscape orientation on Instagram. Today, we are introducing the support for this new format via the Instagram API. This means that all endpoints that return images or videos can now provide URLs of non-square media.

Take a look on their blog: http://developers.instagram.com/post/128288227716/api-migration-for-landscape-and-portrait-formats

Comment: Hi Pedro, thanks for your answer.
I'm aware of what you say, but this is not my problem.

The problem I'm facing is that a few days ago the standard_resolution param from the API was 640x640 pixels, but now the same parameter is returning 320x320 images

Comment: I've checked with the API and it's returning 640x640 for standard_resolution but it's not necessarily square size the height might vary.